# Is this a valid proof technique regarding the divisibility of numbers?

Tags: proof-verification, induction, divisibility

> Claim: All numbers of this sequence are relatively prime to one another:
>   $$2^1 + 1, 2^2 + 1, 2^4 + 1, \ldots, 2^{2^n} + 1$$

So, I decided to include $2^0 + 1$. That way:

Base case:

$$2^0 + 1 = 2$$

Because $2$ is even and the rest are odd, every number after it is coprime to it.

Now, before I get to the inductive step, I also noticed this about any arbitrary number of the sequence:

$$ 2^{2^k} + 1 = 2^{2\cdot2^{k-1}} + 1 = 4^{2^{k-1}} + 1 = (2\cdot2)^{2^{k-1}} +1 = 2^{2^{k-1}}2^{2^{k-1}}+1$$

So, then I decided to say: if I assume every number can be written in this form, and assume my claim holds for $1, \ldots, k$ then if this property holds for $k+1$, the claim is true (but I am not sure you can do this though, can someone confirm, deny, or help me further solidify this idea of mine?):

$$ 2^{2^{k+1}} + 1 = 2^{2\cdot2^k} + 1 = 4^{2^k} + 1 = (2\cdot2)^{2^k} +1 = 2^{2^k}2^{2^k}+1$$

To further elaborate: I am saying that since all $P(k)$ (where $P$ is my original proposition) follow a similar form, if the next number follows that form, the proposition holds true. At the same time, I haven't done induction quite this way before (it is usually easier, and more concrete, so to speak. No "forms" just explicit equations). Hopefully what I am saying makes sense. If you need further clarification please ask.

Comment: I think you have a typo (right at the start)...

Comment: Um. Where? Is it embarrassing or something?

Comment: I already fixed it. I hope …

Comment: @Herald Hanche-Olsen: Thanks!

Comment: Also, induction would not normally be the way to go with this sort of thing. you could use strong induction I think, but that would just be equivalent to doing it as I will outline in my solution

Comment: @Jlamprong: Darn, I'm so used to looking at wolfram alpha, and checking to see if there is a "True", that I guess I didn't look close enough. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E%282*2%5Ek%29+%3D+4%5E%282%5Ek%29

Comment: OK, sorry. I'll delete my previous comment

Comment: @Jlamprong: No, you're right?

Comment: @Jlamprong: It says the only numerical solution is 0... I'm just used to seeing True...

Comment: @Jlamprong: Now I am lost...

Comment: please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution without induction:

Take any $a,b\le n$, assume $a<b$. You need prove that $\gcd(2^{2^a}+1,2^{2^b}+1)=1.$

Let $d=\gcd(2^{2^a}+1,2^{2^b}+1)$. Then $d|2^{2^a}+1$ and $d|2^{2^b}+1$. From $d|2^{2^a}+1$ you'll get $d|2^{2^{a+1}}-1$ since $2^{2^{a+1}}-1=(2^{2^a}+1)(2^{2^a}-1)$. Continuing this process, you'll arrive at $d|2^{2^{a+(b-a)}}-1=2^{2^{b}}-1$. It follows that $d|2^{2^{b}}-1$. Since $d|2^{2^b}+1$ then $d|2$. However, $d$ must be $1$ because it is an odd number.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $p/2^{2^k}+1$ and $p/2^{2^l}+1$ ($p$ divides).

WLOG $k>l$.

Then $ p/2^{2^l} (2^{2^{k-l}}-1)$. Now we know $p \neq 2$ so it divides the parenthesis term.

Factorize the parenthesis term. $p/(2^{2^{k-l-1}}-1)(2^{2^{k-l-1}}+1)$. If $p$ divides the left parenthesis, repeat. If not, it divides the right parenthesis, so start this whole process again with $k=max(k-l-1, l)$,$l=min(k-l-1, l)$. By infinite descent, $p=1$, so the two initial numbers are coprime.

Also, where you thinking of strong/complete induction? The way you could leverage that in this situation is to set $k=n+1$ (where we have proved it up to $n$), then use the induction hypothesis to avoid infinite descent and simplify a little. More complicated if you ask me.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction

Comment: I was thinking induction, but my discrete math skills are bleh, so I just throw things out there and hope something works haha. What ever works, works.